# OData syntax to MongoDB filters

Tags: json, mongodb, asp.net-core, odata

Using MongoDB as a storage database and serving JSON to the client, no intermediate POCOs since I don't really need them, I just want to grab the JSON from the storage and serve it back to the client.

I want to send the filtering conditions from the client to the server and return the JSON result, so I thought this would be a good use case of OData.

I am using ASP.NET Core (Web API), .NET Framework 4.6, is there a way to retrieve the OData string query in the controller and transform it to [MongoDB filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/).

Any alternative practices?